# addthis social share not showing up in modal window

Tags: jquery

I am using addthis for image share and want to implement the same in a pop/modal window, have tried the steps provided in this link https://www.addthis.com/academy/using-addthis-asynchronously/ but still i am not able to get share icon on the modal window. Please help.

For the modal window I am using lightGallery-master, it would be real helpful if u guys can try it on this modal plugin and suggest me.